# CORS issue from CloudFront to server for font

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

We are getting CORS issue for cloudfront to my site for FONT only.

Access to Font at 'http://d2v777xrj.cloudfront.net/assets/simple-line-icons/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons-ff94ad94c3a9d04bd2f80cb3c87dcccb.woff' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: We're having the exact same issue with fonts and tried everything possible. Did you manage to get rid of this issue? Beside invalidating the bucket with fonts, it seems nothing else works.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu this one worked for me.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu: use filter at server side to enable cors specific headers.. It worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

References (After looking into references, found these reference that worked for me. I didnt add any CORS on S3 bucket. Only Cloudfront accessing S3) [for your case change `themes` to `assets`]

https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/doc/font-cors/

http://thelazylog.com/correct-configuration-to-fix-cors-issue-with-cloudfront/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Creating a behavior in Cloudfront to server accept origin header does the job. But before that, you need to configure the application server, Apache (module headers) in my case to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourdomain.com`

Answer (score 9):

Tried everything but nothing worked!
But the solution was very easy just two-step solution and nothing else.

1. Go to S3 Bucket->Permissions->Edit : Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)->paste below configuration. In most of the other articles they are doing mistake of wrong header. you have to put "Origin" in AllowedHeaders.

   ```
    [
        {
            "AllowedHeaders": [
                "Origin"
            ],
            "AllowedMethods": [
                "HEAD",
                "GET"
            ],
            "AllowedOrigins": [
                "http://www.yourdomain.com",
                "https://www.yourdomain.com",
                "https://yourdomain.com",
                "http://yourdomain.com"
            ],
            "ExposeHeaders": [],
            "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
        }
    ]
   ```
2. Go to Cloudfront->Behaviours->Default(*)->Edit
   Change, Cache and origin request settings to : Use legacy cache settings
   Change, Cache Based on Selected Request Headers to : Whitelist
   Then, Add Whitelist Headers to : Origin [Only]

Comment: This really is the solution

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Front Added Origin Policy Recently. Updating the origin policy to s3origin worked for me as below once S3 was configured correctly.

[image: cache and origin policy config]

Comment: you save my day, first it not working. and after check Cloudfront dashboard, it still loading deployment new behavior. so just wait until it done. and check again

Answer (score 1):

**Update July 2023**:

My problem was resolved after applying the following changes:

1. Change the permissions of the bucket on S3:

   - Go to s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3 and select the bucket.
   - After selecting the bucket, click on `Permissions` tab:
     [image: s3 bucket menu]
   - Scroll down to *Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)* section and add the following:

     ```bash
     [
        {
            "AllowedHeaders": [
                "*"
            ],
            "AllowedMethods": [
                "GET",
                "HEAD"
            ],
            "AllowedOrigins": [
                "http://example.com",
            ],
            "ExposeHeaders": []
        }
     ]
     ```
2. Change the behavior of the distribution:

   - Select the behavior and click on edit icon:
     [image: behavior content]
   - Make sure you have added the OPTIONS method for Viewer section:
     [image: Add options]
   - Change the `Origin request policy` permission.
     [image]