# Apache2 + CloudFront: Fonts not loading (CORS Problem) (2023 new Interface)

Tags: apache, cors, amazon-cloudfront

Using CloudFront pointing to my Apache2 server is causing CORS errors for my fonts.

1. I don't understand why this problem effects only fonts.
2. This is the error message I see in my browser:
   [image]
3. This is my current behavior configuration. What do I have to change?
   [image]

Comment: Can you add the necessary [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header through a "Response headers policy"?

Comment: It doesn't help. I selected "SimpleCORS: Allows all origins for simple CORS requests" which sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *

Comment: I uploaded my static files to an S3 Bucket and added this policy to the bucket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932528/cors-issue-from-cloudfront-to-server-for-font#answer-67042151
Now it works. Not sure what was wrong. But I think it is the better solution to serve static files from the s3 bucket.